# "Unhandled Exception: name 'raw_input' is not defined" - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is wrong with this code? It gives me this error:

> "Unhandled Exception: name 'raw_input' is not defined"

I don't know where I am going wrong:

```
def say_hello(nam): 
    nam = raw_input("What is your name? ") 
    if nam != "": 
        return("Hello," + nam + "!" ) 
    else: 
        return("Hello there!")
```

Comment: You are using Python 3. Use `input` instead.

Comment: What python version are you running

Comment: If you are running this with Python 3, you should get a `NameError` exception since `raw_input` exists in Python 2.

Comment: what's wrong is that you're probably using python 3

Comment: Where's the dupe hammer?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Nothing is wrong with using Python 3. What is wrong is using Python 3 and thinking you are using Python 2 ;)

Comment: `return` doesn't need parentheses, by the way

Comment: @DeepSpace or perl while you're at it :)

Comment: Worked it out. Thanks guys